# error_log() output for print_r() appearing on page

Tags: php, plugin-development, errors, debug

I am trying to debug a plugin and am using `error_log()` in various places to see what various things are. I am using the following:

```
error_log( print_r( $variable ) );
```

When I look at `debug.log`, all I see is `1` and the actual output of the `error_log()` function is sent to the browser instead.

I know another plugin is not doing this as all are disabled with the exception of the one I am writing. In my `wp-config.php`, I have defined `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` as `false`.

The same thing happens if I use `var_dump()` and `var_export()`. Other functions like `gettype()` work just fine.

Is there any way to get the output into `debug.log`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) function accept second parameter for `return` so it retrun the variable instead of printing it.

```
print_r($expression, $return)
```

So you can do

```
error_log( print_r( $variable, true ) );
```

Comment: Thanks. Figured it would be something that simple that I was missing :)

Answer (score 2):

If your variable is just a string, then you can simply use `error_log ( $variable )`. If it's an object or an array, other than using `print_r()`, you can serialize it too:

```
error_log ( serialize ( $variable ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer is correct, I wanted to include an answer that expands the explanation for clarity.

`print_r()` accepts two arguments ([see the documentation for this function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)), the second of which is optional and you have omitted.  The first argument is the expression to be printed. The second specifies whether the value is returned or printed.

When the second argument is omitted, its default value is `false` and therefore it prints the result immediately.  If this argument is false, `print_r()` will return `true` (which is displayed as "1" in the error log).

```
$result = print_r( $variable );
```

The returned result here is `true` (displayed as "1").

You're passing the returned result of `print_r()` to `error_log()`.  For the reason described above, this result is "1" and that is why you're getting 1 as the entry in the log.

In order to get a result to contain the expression in `$variable` and pass it to the `error_log()` function, you need `print_r()` to return the expression as the result.  You can do that by specifying the second argument as TRUE.

```
$result = print_r( $variable, true );
```

Now the returned result of `print_r()` is the expression contained in `$variable` and you can pass it to `error_log()`:

```
$result = print_r( $variable, true );
error_log( $result );
```

***OR:***

```
error_log( print_r( $variable, true ) );
```

If you want to take this a step further, you could write a utility function for writing to the log that would handle determining if `$variable` was an array or an object and thus required `print_r()`, or if it could simply be passed as a string.  This makes it easy to handle debug logging since you don't have to be concerned with the variable type in order to pass it for logging.  I have written such [a utility along with a detailed explanation here](https://wpbitz.com/utility-function-for-the-wordpress-error-log/).

**Side note on the PHP functions you mentioned:** No matter how experienced you are, it's always helpful to review the documentation of the functions you are using in order to make sure you know what they actually do.  I have linked to the `print_r()` documentation above, which describes exactly what was talked about in both this *and* the accepted answer. But also mentioned were some other PHP functions that worked or didn't work.  Let's consider those:

[`var_dump()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php): The documentation indicates that this function does not return a result. In order to pass something to `error_log()` for including in the error log, it needs to be an expression contained in a variable.  This function does not return anything, it only outputs to the screen. So you can't use it to pass anything to `error_log()`.

[`var_export()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php): Similar to `print_r()` in that you have a second, optional argument to either return a result or print to the screen. Define the second argument as `true` to be able to return a result for `error_log()`.

[`gettype()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) always returns the type of the variable. So you have something you can pass to `error_log()` by default.  That is why it worked.